# Problem with CAGradientLayer in a custom UIView within a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, gradient

I have a somewhat special situation that I need help with. I have a CustomView which I am placing in every UITableViewCell in my UITableView. No problems there.

Within my CustomView is a UILabel which displays some text given to it. Depending on the length of the text, the width of the CustomView grows/shrinks. All fine.

The problem I am having is with a sublayer in my CustomView which is a gradient (CAGradientLayer). The gradient size will not grow/shrink off screen on cells not in view.

Let me show you some code... I create my CustomView like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    CustomView *custom = [[CustomView alloc] init];
    custom.tag = 777;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:custom];
    [custom release];

}

}
```

I don't initWithFrame at this stage as the cell could get reused and the width is always wrong. Once the cell is there, I call a method configureCell: where I do the following:

```
CGSize teamMaxSize = CGSizeMake(300, 18);
CGSize teamNewSize = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"category"] 
    sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:kFontSizeTeam]
    constrainedToSize:teamMaxSize
    lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CustomView *lozenge = (CustomView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:777];
lozenge.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, teamNewSize.width+12, 18);
[lozenge resetSize];
[lozenge setLabel:[managedObject valueForKey:@"category"]];
```

This works fine, the width of my CustomView is setup as per the length of the 'category' key. The resetSize; method above simply resizes the UILabel I mentioned before to the new frame of the CustomView before I fill it with the value.

Anyway, back to my issue. I am creating the background gradient in the drawRect: method of my CustomView. It works fine, however is the size of the CustomView at init. After I resize I need to resize the gradient.frame. So, I tried adding

```
gradient.frame = self.bounds
```

When I call resetSize in my aforementioned code. However when scrolling through the UITableView I can see the gradient literally filling from left to right as it loads into view. Is there anyway I can get this to happen 'off screen' so the CustomView is filled with the gradient as soon as it appears?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a gradient in `drawRect:`, have you considered using `CAGradientLayer` as the layer class of your custom view, e.g.:

```
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAGradientLayer class];
}
```

Then you can perform any setup of your gradient in your initializer, via `self.layer`.

Comment: but the width of my gradient cannot be set when I initialize the CustomView... I have to wait...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but if you are trying to create a gradient background for your cell, I'd suggest creating a simple `CustomBackgroundView` class as described (with a `CAGradientLayer` backing) and attaching it to your cell's `backgroundView` property. It should be automatically sized appropriately for your cell, and you can do the rest of your custom drawing in your `CustomView`.

Comment: I'm creating a gradient in the background of my CustomView. Imagine the custom view as a lozenge button with a line of text in it. It is within my cell with other objects...

Comment: On further consideration, is `gradient.frame = self.bounds` happening within a `UIView` animation context?

Comment: No, it's just within a custom method to resize the UILabel.

Comment: It sounds like it's animating the frame change when you want it to take place immediately. Just for kicks you could try wrapping the call with `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]; ... [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];` or temporarily disable them entirely.

Comment: it made no difference I'm afraid.

Comment: Oops, that probably should have been `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]; gradient.frame = self.bounds; [UIView commitAnimations];` -- I'll edit the answer if this works for you.

Comment: Is this happening on the simulator, device, or both?

Comment: Also, if `gradient` above is a `CAGradientLayer` and not a `UIView` (as I hastily assumed), perhaps this would work:
    
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
    gradient.frame = self.bounds;
    [CATransaction commit];